# Непонятное форматирование по временной зоне

Tags: php, timezone

Время = 2017-07-09 23:23:00
Часовой пояс сервера Europe/Moscow

```php
date_default_timezone_get(); // Europe/Moscow

$date = '2017-07-09 23:23:00';
echo date("d M Yг., в H:i", strtotime($date)); // 07 Jul 2017г., в 23:23

$idf = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ru_RU',
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    null, // timezone
    null, // calendar
    "dd MMM YYYY'г., в' HH:mm"
);
echo  $idf->format(strtotime($date )); // 07 июля 2017г., в 00:23
```

Почему происходит разница во времени?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить временную зону:

```
date_default_timezone_get(); // Europe/Moscow

$date = '2017-07-09 23:23:00';
echo date("d M Yг., в H:i", strtotime($date)); // 07 Jul 2017г., в 23:23

$idf = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ru_RU',
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    date_default_timezone_get(), // timezone
    null, // calendar
    "dd MMM YYYY'г., в' HH:mm"
);
echo  $idf->format(strtotime($date )); // 07 июля 2017г., в 23:23
```

или, если проблема останится, измените её вручную:

```
date_default_timezone_get(); // Europe/Moscow

$date = '2017-07-09 23:23:00';
echo date("d M Yг., в H:i", strtotime($date)); // 07 Jul 2017г., в 23:23

$idf = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ru_RU',
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'Europe/Moscow', // timezone
    null, // calendar
    "dd MMM YYYY'г., в' HH:mm"
);
echo  $idf->format(strtotime($date )); // 07 июля 2017г., в 23:23
```

Comment: Нет это не помогает, это может быть связанно с тем  что Россия перестала переходить на  летнее/зимнее время, а в  ICU остались старые данные? Сейчас на сервере установлена  libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64

Comment: Я просто на своём тестовом сервере на Windows не смог воссоздать эту ситуацию, и дал приблизительный ответ